# Python баг с уведомлениями plyer.notification.notify

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, уведомления

Проблема заключается в том, что после отправки уведомлений через скрипт, они начинаются копиться в списке активных программ ( снизу справа галочка в windows), при наведении на них пропадают. Использую:

```
plyer.notification.notify()
```

скриншот бага:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]